# How to make a AVPlayerViewController go to fullscreen programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I'm trying to make a [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/) go to full screen mode programmatically, coming from "embedded" mode, however this does not appear to be possible with the published API.

Is there a workaround that I'm missing? I'm interested in obtaining the same animation to the one that you get when the user presses the full screen button on the bottom right of the controls.

Using MPMoviePlayerController is not a viable alternative since I might have more than one video playing at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same position as you. It seems like currently there is no work around for this. @Stefan's answer doesn't actually "full screen" the player but just makes it bigger which as you say causes the controls not to get updated properly and there's no way for you to know if the person clicked the done button or collapse button. Not that matters though as it will start with the expand arrow anyways which is incorrect. In my case I'm going to have to modify the app to work around AVPlayerViewController's limitations. Hopefully they'll fix this at some point.

Comment: Same problem.  This is odd because there's an [apple tech talk](http://asciiwwdc.com/2016/sessions/506?q=avplayerviewcontroller) where they say you should present the view controller to make it full-screen.

Answer (score 16):

AVPlayerViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, so it is presentable like any other view controller subclass. Are you able to use `presentViewController:animated:completion`?

```
self.avPlayerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:self.avPlayerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This then shows the "Done" button in the top left-hand corner.

Comment: Can't make this happen, when device is tethering (blue top bar). The old MPMoviePlayer was able to go fullscreen even in this case.

Comment: This wouldn't use the default transition animation for going fullscreen, right? Instead it uses a modal.

Answer (score 15):

**Updated for iOS 11**

There is no supported way to programmatically go fullscreen with AVPlayerViewController (a bit of an oversight in my opinion).

However, [AVPlayerViewController does contain a private method](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/AVPlayerViewController.h#L127) that does exactly that. You'll have to decide for yourself whether you'd want to use it or not given you're not supposed to call private methods.

AVPlayerViewController+Fullscreen.h

```
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface AVPlayerViewController (Fullscreen)

-(void)goFullscreen;

@end
```

AVPlayerViewController+Fullscreen.m

```
#import "AVPlayerViewController+Fullscreen.h"

@implementation AVPlayerViewController (Fullscreen)

-(void)goFullscreen {
    NSString *selectorForFullscreen = @"transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:";
    if (@available(iOS 11.3, *)) {
        selectorForFullscreen = @"transitionToFullScreenAnimated:interactive:completionHandler:";
    } else if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        selectorForFullscreen = @"transitionToFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:";
    }
    SEL fsSelector = NSSelectorFromString([@"_" stringByAppendingString:selectorForFullscreen]);
    if ([self respondsToSelector:fsSelector]) {
        NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:fsSelector]];
        [inv setSelector:fsSelector];
        [inv setTarget:self];

        NSInteger index = 2; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set
        BOOL animated = YES;
        [inv setArgument:&(animated) atIndex:index];
        index++;

        if (@available(iOS 11.3, *)) {
            BOOL interactive = YES;
            [inv setArgument:&(interactive) atIndex:index]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
            index++;
        }

        id completionBlock = nil;
        [inv setArgument:&(completionBlock) atIndex:index];
        [inv invoke];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Does this still work in iOS 10? I see that the controller responds to the selector, but nothing actually happens when invoked.

Comment: Thanks @ToddH Its working!! how can we add an observer for this fullscreen and small screen transition?

Comment: @VinuDavidJose on the AVPlayerViewController you have to addObserver:forKeyPath:"videoBounds" and then in the observeValue  method that gets called: `DispatchQueue.main.async { isFullscreen = playerViewController.view.bounds != playerViewController.contentOverlayView?.bounds ... }`

Comment: @ToddH I have used this idea to go fullscreen from tableviewcell. but its crashing on ios 10 devices after showing fullscreen. but working perfectly on ios 11 iPhone X

Comment: please find the crash log *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<AVEmbeddedPlaybackControlsViewController: 0x7f8e9ca22200> should have parent view controller:<AVPlayerViewController: 0x7f8e9bb62e00> but actual parent is:<AVFullScreenViewController: 0x7f8e9adc4fa0>'

Comment: In iOS 11.3 method changed to "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:interactive:completionHandler:" (interactive - bool parameter)

Comment: Using this private method..will appstore accept it?

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: Swift 4 version of ToddH's answer:

```
private func enterFullscreen(playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController) {

    let selectorName: String = {
        if #available(iOS 11.3, *) {
            return "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:interactive:completionHandler:"
        } else if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            return "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"
        } else {
            return "_transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:"
        }
    }()
    let selectorToForceFullScreenMode = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)

    if playerViewController.responds(to: selectorToForceFullScreenMode) {
        playerViewController.perform(selectorToForceFullScreenMode, with: true, with: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As a little iOS 14 update to ToddH's answer: the [private API](https://github.com/SparkDev97/iOS14-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/AVPlayerViewController.h#L249) to call is `enterFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:`. So here's an extension on AVPlayerViewController to enter full screen.

```swift
extension AVPlayerViewController {
    func enterFullScreen(animated: Bool) {
        perform(NSSelectorFromString("enterFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"), with: animated, with: nil)
    }
    func exitFullScreen(animated: Bool) {
        perform(NSSelectorFromString("exitFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"), with: animated, with: nil)
    }
}
```

This implementation doesn't offer a completion callback. If you pass a Swift closure to the `completionHandler` parameter, it crashes in the underlying Obj-C API. I haven't investigated how to pass the closure to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

In iOS11 there are 2 new properties for `AVPlayerViewController`: `entersFullScreenWhenPlaybackBegins` and `exitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds`. You can enable full screen mode right after playback begins and disable it when playback ends with these properties. If you need to enable fullscreen mode after some delay you can use private API methods as [ToddH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428767/toddh) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36853320/2229783). However in iOS11 `_transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:` method is not available anymore, there is the same method called `_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:`. The second method accepts the same arguments as the first one.

I can show an example how to use it. First of all you need to create `AVPlayerViewController` instance in your `UIViewController`:

```
private let playerController : AVPlayerViewController = {

    if let urlForPlayer = URL(string: "your_video_url") {

        $0.player = AVPlayer(url: urlForPlayer)
    }
    return $0
} (AVPlayerViewController())
```

Then you need to setup view for AVPlayerViewController and add it to your current controller view. Function `setupAVplayerController` can do it for you:

```
private func setupAVplayerController() {

    self.addChildViewController(self.playerController)
    self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
    self.view.addSubview(self.playerController.view)
    self.playerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Function `enterFullscreen` forces full screen mode for `AVPlayerViewController`:

```
private func enterFullscreen(playerViewController:AVPlayerViewController) {

    let selectorName : String = {

        if #available(iOS 11, *) {

            return "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"
        } else {

            return "_transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:"
        }
    }()
    let selectorToForceFullScreenMode = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)
    if playerViewController.responds(to: selectorToForceFullScreenMode) {

            playerViewController.perform(selectorToForceFullScreenMode, with: true, with: nil)
    }
}
```

And now you need to call all these functions where you need it, for example in `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //Your code

    self.setupAVplayerController()
    self.playerController.player?.play()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {

        self.enterFullscreen(playerViewController:self.playerController)
    }
}
```

Don't forget that this solution based on private API calls that is not recommended to use.

Comment: @karthikeyan If you need to force full screen mode for AVPlayerViewController and you can use private API calls, just copy code from my answer to your project and after that call myPlayerViewController. forceFullScreenMode(). Or did you find some errors in this answer?

Comment: @karthikeyan Or maybe this code not working for you?

Comment: yes it  is not working, I am showing player half of view very first initial load, when user click full screen button, it has to show  as landscape mode..

Is there anyway to find out entering full or exit screen? I have Tried many ways nothing helps

Comment: @karthikeyan What OS/device are you using for testing?

Comment: iPhone 6s with iOS 11

Comment: @karthikeyan Have you tried to launch this code on iOS10? Or you don't need to support iOS10?

Comment: @karthikeyan You can also try to change first argument for function "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:" from "true" to "false". Did it solved your problem?

Comment: is it possible to provide sample? I dont understand how extension will work my secanrio..Did you understand my flow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156070/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-karthikeyan).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, any way its opening by default not from avplayer fullscreen action.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 version for the answer of ToddH:

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {

    func goFullScreen() {
        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("_transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:")
        if self.responds(to: selector) {
            // first argument is animated (true for me), second is completion handler (nil in my case)
            self.perform(selector, with: true, with: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the **videoGravity** property of AVPlayerViewController.

```
if(fullscreen)
{
    [self.avPlayerController 
     setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
}
else
{
    [self.avPlayerController 
    setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not have the need to use any restricted code.

For this, I am assuming that you have added the `AVPlayerViewController` as a child view controller.

Then for that you will first have to remove the child view controller and then present it again as a fullscreen controller as well attach the `AVPlayer` view properly to it's parent view.

Here is how I did it. Please note that I am using a library called `Easy Peasy` for restoring the `playerVC.view` constraints - one can do that with proper constraints as well.

```
    @objc func fullscreenButtonClicked() {

        playerVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        playerVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        playerVC.removeFromParentViewController()


        self.present(self.playerVC, animated: false, completion: {
            self.playerVC.view.easy.layout(Top(), Right(), Left(), Bottom())
        })
    }
```

Comment: I could do `UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()` instead of setting `playerVC.view` constraints

Answer (score 0):

For an 'embedded' `AVPlayerViewController` instance, it is quite easy to programmatically have it start playback in full screen mode, and without hacking anything (calling private methods). You just need to set its `entersFullScreenWhenPlaybackBegins` property to true.

You need to add the controller as a child VC to the main VC, and that's basically it. In `viewDidAppear(_:)` you need to call `play()` method on the controller's `player` property - playback will be automatically started in fullscreen.

It's often best to check Apple sample code for these kind of tricky APIs; I think this one might be useful for a lot of AVPlayer use cases: [Using AVKit in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/using_avkit_in_ios).

Comment: Sounds so simple. But playback does not start in fullscreen for me even with `entersFullScreenWhenPlaybackBegins` set to true.

Comment: Hmm. Note the Apple documentation for that property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/2875792-entersfullscreenwhenplaybackbegi -- A Boolean value that determines whether the player automatically displays in full screen *when the user taps the play button*.  Sure enough, the player goes in to full screen when playback is started by manually pressing play. Not when starting programmatically.