# Video play using AVPlayer in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've a video which is being played by AVPlayer in a particular ViewController. When  tapping on the Full Screen icon in the AVPlayer control bar, I want the video to be played in landscape mode in the same ViewController. I'm attaching a screenshot for this scenario.[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817667/how-to-make-a-avplayerviewcontroller-go-to-fullscreen-programmatically/33785005 and when click on FS Icon just change the orientation of VC.

Comment: I want to play the video in landscape mode while tapping the full screen button

Comment: I did it using MPMoviePlayer but it is depricated in ios 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to write the below code for orienting the view controller

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Whenever you click the FS btn,try to orient the VC

Comment: Please Help me Elan

Comment: you have to check for the methods for orientation with iOS9