# Exit AVPlayerViewController fullscreen programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I am try customize AVPlayerViewController show fullscreen and I search link:
[How to make a AVPlayerViewController go to fullscreen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817667/how-to-make-a-avplayerviewcontroller-go-to-fullscreen-programmatically). It work when I use private method, but I can't find method exit full screen.

Comment: Any success on it ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this problem that works for me

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {

func goFullScreen() {
    let selectorName: String = {
        if #available(iOS 11.3, *) {
            return "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:interactive:completionHandler:"
        } else if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            return "_transitionToFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"
        } else {
            return "_transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:"
        }
    }()
    let selectorToForceFullScreenMode = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)

    if self.responds(to: selectorToForceFullScreenMode) {
        self.perform(selectorToForceFullScreenMode, with: true, with: nil)
    }
}

func quitFullScreen() {
    let selectorName: String = {
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            return "_transitionFromFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"
        } else {
            return "_transitionFromFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:"
        }
    }()
    let selectorToForceQuitFullScreenMode = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)

    if self.responds(to: selectorToForceQuitFullScreenMode) {
        self.perform(selectorToForceQuitFullScreenMode, with: true, with: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: your solution doesn't work on ios 13. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116399/avplayerviewcontroller-pops-all-uiviewcontrollers-from-uinavigationcontroller-wh

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that you can go and exit fullscreen.

If someone look for an answer, I hope it helps...

```
import AVKit

extension AVPlayerViewController {

    func goFullScreen() {
        let selectorName = "enterFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"
        let selectorToForceFullScreenMode = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)

        if self.responds(to: selectorToForceFullScreenMode) {
            self.perform(selectorToForceFullScreenMode, with: true, with: nil)
        }
    }

    func quitFullScreen() {
        let selectorName  "exitFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"
        let selectorToForceQuitFullScreenMode = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)

        if self.responds(to: selectorToForceQuitFullScreenMode) {
            self.perform(selectorToForceQuitFullScreenMode, with: true, with: nil)
        }
    } 
}
```

Let me know if work for you.

Comment: @AMIT What is your version? And how did you add avplayercontroller to view?

Comment: I used iOS version 12.1  @Rafaela Lourenço