# Xamarin.Forms AVPlayer exit fullscreen from method

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a Xamarin application which plays a video for 30 seconds and then shows a dialog. The user can continue to watch (dismiss the dialog) or click an action in the dialog (which then should close full-screen and navigate elsewhere in the app).

I have this working on the simulator. However, when I run the following code on an real iOS device, the app crashes without any stacktrace.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
var openLink = await _userDialogs.ConfirmAsync("...", cancelText: "Dismiss", okText: "Yes");

if (openLink)
{
    await _navigationService.Close(scope);

    MessagingCenter.Send(Application.Current, "CloseFullscreen");
}
```

**VideoRenderer.cs**

```
_playerViewController = new AVPlayerViewController()
{
    ExitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds = true
};

player = new AVPlayer();
_playerViewController.Player = player;

...

SetNativeControl(_playerViewController.View);

 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application>(this, "CloseFullscreen", (app) =>
 {
     BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
     {
         var selectorName = "exitFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:";

         var selector = new ObjCRuntime.Selector(selectorName);

         if (_playerViewController.RespondsToSelector(selector))
             _playerViewController.PerformSelector(selector, NSObject.FromObject(true), 0);
     });
});
```

*Please note that I am **not** using the CrossMediaManager plugin due to this bug: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/629*

Comment: Hi, you could have a try with modifying the orientation of device to **Portrait**, then can exit the full screen.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, I did. Unfortunately still the same result...

Comment: Do you modify the frame of `AVPlayer` when orientation be changed?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT No, the screen orientation remains the same, the view in which the player is located also remains the same size.

Comment: There is no error logs? You could check the device logs, maybe can see the detailed logs.

Comment: No exception from Rider or Visual Studio. I also did not find any exceptions in the  device logs: https://pastebin.com/raw/uZhtaiSm

Comment: Yeah, from the device logs, can not finding related information about exiting full screen of  `AVPlayer`. You need to check whether catch the logs after sending message.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Nothing there either...

Comment: If you have another physical devices to test, that will be better to know whether it not works for all pjysical devices.

Comment: Tried it as wel on an iPhone 8, iPhone X and iPad Air 2. Also doesn’t work there.

Comment: Hi, if you could share a sample project link in question, I will check in local site to find whether there is a solution.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sure thing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTLR49ea9Osb-_oXiS5inT0kluPQBJUh

I have integrated it on the "Play Web Video" page. After you click on the list item, a video page opens. Then open fullscreen and a popup will show after 10 seconds. After the popup a message will be send to the renderer using Xamarin's messaging system. Which invokes the selector. Many thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have checked in local site, however it occurs the same with yours in a physical device. And also find a similar issue about this, it seems only occurs above iOS 13. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794310/exit-avplayerviewcontroller-fullscreen-programmatically. If later find the solution will update here.